# reexport and flatten both the default & named exports using es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A folder `folder` has several js files. one of them, `var.js` exports default & name variable at the same times:

```
export a ...
export b ...
export default c ...
```

I can then write: `import c,{a,b} from "folder/var";`

In `folder`, I want to write `index.js` to reexport variables from `var.js` and be able to write:

`import {c,a,b} from "folder";`:

I wrote in `index.js`:

```
export * from "./var"
```

From what I understand from [exploringjs.com section 16.4.4 All exporting styles](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html), It will export only `a` and `b` from `var.js`. How can I "flatten" export from `var.js` in `index.js`?

Comment: Why would it only export `a` and `b`? It will also export `default`.

Comment: What you write makes me realize that `default` is actually a variable named `default` that I can use as it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but you can do the following:

```
export {a,b, default as c} from "./var";
```